# Vuetify v-form validation

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a `v-form` like this:

```
<v-form ref="form" v-model="formOk">
    <v-row dense>
        <!-- nome step corso -->
        <v-col cols="12" md="6">
        <field :model.sync="editedItem.nome" label="Nome" :rules="textRules(3,30)"></field>
        </v-col>
        <!-- data e ora -->
        <v-col cols="12" md="12">
            <DataOraPicker :model.sync="editedItem.data" label_data="Data 1ª sessione" label_ora="Ora 1ª sessione"
                hint_data="Data della prima/unica sessione della sezione"
                hint_ora="Ora della prima/unica sessione della sezione"
                :rules_data="data1sessioneRules()" :rules_ora="ora1sessioneRules()"
            />
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
</v-form>
```

where `form` is the ref and `formOk` is a data (set by default to `true`).

At the beginning, I put wrong data to make form false, I got the red error message and `formOK` become `false`
After this I put correct data in the form, I run `this.$refs.form.validate()`, red errors disappear but `formOk` still `false`.

What can I do?

---

Update:
Validation errors were thrown on disabled fields with persistent hint, so therefore they were not clearly visible.

Comment: it should work fine. Check this example: https://codepen.io/proofzy/pen/XWNMMMd

Comment: Yes... validation errors were thrown on disabled fields with persistent hint, so therefore they were not clearly visible.